# Get a company followers count on LinkedIn

Tags: c#, api, linkedin-api, spring-social

I'm trying to get the number of followers of a company on Linked in.
I use this code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/?id=SomeCompanyID:(num-followers)") as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "Get";
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("MyAppClientID", "MyAppClientSecret");

using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)   // I'm getting "(401) Unauthorized" exception at this line.
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"WriteText.txt", result);
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

I'm not sure about my syntax and the way I provide credentials, but I don't know how to do so correctly, and documentation is not clear at this point.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: I take it you have added the actual values of your AppClientID and AppClientSecret as provided from the linked in API?

Comment: I didn't get your point. You took what??

Comment: have you added the actual values of your AppClientID and AppClientSecret as provided from the linked in API? you get those values when you register your app at https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps/

Comment: Yes, I added the actual values.

Comment: @Dr-Maf did you get a solution to this problem? if you figured it out and the solution is not one already listed please add it so others may benefit from the solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I didn't find a solution, yet. I'm still investigating to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't registered your application or more accurately you haven't updated the code sample with your own ClientKey and Secret value.

You obtain them from https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps/

You can also find more information about it here https://developer.linkedin.com/support/faq

> **Where can I find my API key?**
>
> Click on the My Apps link in the top navigation menu to manage your
>   LinkedIn applications.
>
> From here, you can create a new application if you don't already have
>   one or view the details of your existing applications.  You will find
>   your Client ID (otherwise known as API Key/ID or Consumer Key/ID)
>   listed in the "Authentication" side nav link, underneath the header
>   "Authentication Keys".

Alternatively, you may be using an old format of Rest API call, accoring to this page (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages), the new format is as follows

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}/num-followers?format=json
```

> **Get a company's followers, by segment**
>
> If you choose to target content that you share on behalf of a company,
>   there is a minumum number of followers that must make up the segment
>   you are targeting before you will be able to successfully share the
>   targeted content.  This request allows you to get a follower-count for
>   a specific segment to ensure you are at or over the minimum
>   requirement for the target segment for the company specified by the
>   {id} value in the request. Optional Parameters
>
> https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}/num-followers?format=json
>
> **sample response**
>   1147037